# Garbage Collection in W3WP process

Tags: .net, debugging, iis, memory, garbage-collection

Debugging a performance issue where one of our servers uses more CPU than expected I'm currently focusing on GC because % time in GC seems to be around 30 which I find to be too high.

Also I notice a pattern where CPU usage slowly creeps up until pool recycle every night at midnight. LOH size also creeps up (I suspect its because we cache user information) which leads me to think that the growing LOH is the reason for the CPU and % in GC is creeping up until recycle. I also noticed a lot of gen2 collections.

[image: GC gens]

Looking at this graph two things strikes me:

1) Is this patter for GC normal? I would think that gen 2 was collected a lot fewer times.

2) What is going on at 17:40? The servers has two running app pools (one just a dummy website, and one doing all the work), for me it looks like they switch place at 17:40, no recycle or anything seem to have occurred.

Time in GC and alloc B/sec is following along in a strange but rising pattern:

[image: % Time in GC and alloc]

Comment: Does % in GC also trend up? It's hidden here.

Comment: Since time in GC seems to correlate strongly with allocation rate here. Seems completely health. From the charts I can't see an increase in LOH size but I take your work for it. Can you profile the app and see what's using CPU? PerfView can do that non-intrusively. Make sure to set up symbols.

Comment: I have no experience with PerfView, but I will give it a try. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what's going on at 17:40.

However, this pattern is normal for GC. Gen2 will be collected a lot fewer times and Gen0 will be collected more than Gen1 and Gen 1 will be collected more than Gen 2.

***Just a little introduction how GC works.***

When it comes to managed objects, there are three Small Object Heaps(SOH) and one Large Object Heap(LOH).

**Large Object Heap (LOH)**

Objects that are larger than 85KB are going to LOH straight away. There are some risks if you have too many large objects. That's a different discussion, for more details have a look at [The Dangers of the Large Object Heap](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/the-dangers-of-the-large-object-heap/)

**Small Object Heap (SOH) : Gen0, Gen1, Gen2**

Garbage collector uses a clever algorithm to execute the garbage collecton only when it is required. Full garbage collection process is an expensive operation which shouldn't happen too often. So, it has broken its SOH into three parts and as you have noticed each Gen has a specified amount of memory.

Every small object (<85KB) initially going to Gen0. When Gen0 is full, garbage collection executes only for Gen0. It checks all instances that are in Gen0 and clears/releases memory that is used by any unnecessary objects(non-referenced, out of scoped or disposed objects). And then it copies all the required (in used) instances to Gen1.

Above process is actually occurs even when you execute below: (not required to call manually)

```
// Perform a collection of generation 0 only.
GC.Collect(0);
```

In this way, Garbage collector clears the memory that are allocated for short lived instances first (strings which is immutable, variables in methods or smaller scopes).

When GC is keep doing this operation at one stage, Gen1 overflows. Then it does the same operation to Gen1. It clears all the unnecessary memory in Gen1 and copies all required ones to Gen2.

Above process is occurs when you execute below manually (not required to call manually)

```
// Perform a collection of all generations up to and including 1.
GC.Collect(1);
```

When GC is keep doing this operation at one stage if Gen2 overflows it tries to clean Gen2.

Above process is occurs even when you execute below manually (not required to do manually)

```
// Perform a collection of all generations up to and including 2.
GC.Collect(2);
```

If the amount of memory needs to be copy from Gen1 to Gen2 is greater than the amount of memory available in Gen2, GC throws out of memory exception.

Comment: Thanks, I get how GC in .NET works. As you write gen 0 should be collected a lot as it is inexpensive to do, gen 1 fewer times and gen 2 only rarely. As Tess suggests here [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/06/22/asp-net-case-study-high-cpu-in-gc-large-objects-and-high-allocation-rates.aspx) a thumb rule is a ratio of 100/10/1 between the gen collections. What I see here is a ratio of 100/88/78 which means that nearly all collections are full collections. I need pointer on how to troubleshoot this issue....

Comment: Actually I have been debugging this issue for a while, I found a few places in our code base where  GC.GetTotalMemory(true) was called for performance logging, as you probably know this triggers full gc and because the method was called every one minute it was putting great pressure on the GC, removing this code helped a lot but the GC is still working overtime...

Comment: "this pattern is normal for GC" ??? Why is that? Why does CPU rise over time here?

Comment: A search for \bGB\b as regex in whole code base reveals that GC.GetTotalMemory(false) is called in a few places, but that's it, and this should not mess with the GC. Is there other ways to mess with the GC besides calling methods on the static GC object and by allocating too much stuff?